# How can I test in Foundry with multiple addresses?

Tags: foundry, forge

Is there any way to test with multiple addresses using forge like you can in [Truffle](https://trufflesuite.com/) or [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/)? Like Truffle gives you an array of addresses you can call and that changes the `msg.sender` calling the function.

I'm trying to test these methods:

```js
function addMember(address _member) public onlyOwner {
        balance[_member] = TOTAL_MEMBER_TOKENS;
        totalTokens += TOTAL_MEMBER_TOKENS;
    }

function addProposal(string calldata _proposal) public onlyMember {
        proposals.push(Proposal(_proposal, 0, 0));
        emit NewProposal(_proposal);
    }
```

I want to use the owner address to `addMember` then use the members address to call `addProposal`. How would I do that? If this can't be done then what is the address that I should pass to `addMember` to make the owner of the contract a member so I can test with only one address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundry's `anvil` network provides you with a list of 10 addresses and their private keys:

```js
Available Accounts
==================

(0) "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(1) "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(2) "0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(3) "0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(4) "0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(5) "0x9965507D1a55bcC2695C58ba16FB37d819B0A4dc" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(6) "0x976EA74026E726554dB657fA54763abd0C3a0aa9" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(7) "0x14dC79964da2C08b23698B3D3cc7Ca32193d9955" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(8) "0x23618e81E3f5cdF7f54C3d65f7FBc0aBf5B21E8f" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)
(9) "0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720" (10000.000000000000000000 ETH)

Private Keys
==================

(0) 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
(1) 0x59c6995e998f97a5a0044966f0945389dc9e86dae88c7a8412f4603b6b78690d
(2) 0x5de4111afa1a4b94908f83103eb1f1706367c2e68ca870fc3fb9a804cdab365a
(3) 0x7c852118294e51e653712a81e05800f419141751be58f605c371e15141b007a6
(4) 0x47e179ec197488593b187f80a00eb0da91f1b9d0b13f8733639f19c30a34926a
(5) 0x8b3a350cf5c34c9194ca85829a2df0ec3153be0318b5e2d3348e872092edffba
(6) 0x92db14e403b83dfe3df233f83dfa3a0d7096f21ca9b0d6d6b8d88b2b4ec1564e
(7) 0x4bbbf85ce3377467afe5d46f804f221813b2bb87f24d81f60f1fcdbf7cbf4356
(8) 0xdbda1821b80551c9d65939329250298aa3472ba22feea921c0cf5d620ea67b97
(9) 0x2a871d0798f97d79848a013d4936a73bf4cc922c825d33c1cf7073dff6d409c6
```

You can easily use these to test your functions.

Another solution you could use would be to simply use `vm.prank` with random addresses, such as `address(0)`, `address(1)`, and `address(1337)`.

First you can test `addMember()` by calling it from the owner's address with a random address such as `address(1)`.

For example:

```js
function test_addMember() {
vm.prank(owner);
yourContract.addMember(address(1));
}
```

*`vm.prank` allows you to change `msg.sender` for the next function call.*

Now that `address(1)` is a member we can call `addProposal()` from that address:

```js
function test_addProposal() {
vm.prank(address(1));
yourContract.addProposal(yourProposal);
}
```

You can add some conditional or `assert` after the function call to ensure it did what you expected it to.

You can read more about Foundry's `anvil` [here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/anvil/) and more about `vm.prank` [here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/prank).